# Steps to troubleshoot new Nginx installation

Tags: nginx

I am setting up Nginx on a new server running Ubuntu 12.04. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed nginx:

   ```
   aptitude -y install nginx
   ```
2. Removed the default vhost config:

   ```
   rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
   ```
3. Added my own vhost config:

   ```
   mv myapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```
4. Started nginx:

   ```
   service nginx start
   ```

The vhost file looks something like this:

```
upstream unicorn_server {
  server unix:/tmp/APP_NAME.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  server_name _;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/APP_NAME.access.log;

  root /var/www/APP_NAME/current/public;

  # auth

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /var/www/APP_NAME/current/public;
  }
}
```

I can confirm that Nginx is running:

```
service nginx status
 * nginx is running
```

However, I can't seem to access it:

```
curl 123.456.789.0 # example IP
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I have not yet started the unicorn server, but that should not be a problem. I would expect to see a 502 error if Unicorn isn't running. There is no output in the error or access logs. What steps should I take to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: That's not a valid IP address. And `curl` is notorious for hiding the actual cause of the error; try using `wget` instead.

Comment: The output of `wget` is nearly identical: `Connecting to [example IP]...failed: Connection refused.`

Comment: what does `netstat -ntlp` say? Is nginx listening on port 80? Do you see the service in the processlist?

Comment: @etagenklo netstat only shows `sshd`. Running `top`, I see `nginx` pop up occasionally, plus `service nginx status` shows that it's running. The vhost file states that it should be listening on port 80.

Comment: Did you also check your nginx main log (usually at /var/log/nginx/) for error messages? Did you try to add the IP to your `Listen` directive?

Comment: @etagenklo Yes, there is no output in either `access.log` or `error.log`. Adding the IP to the `listen` directive did not have any effect.

Comment: FYI: I just re-enabled the default vhost and it works, so there's something wrong in my vhost configuration.

Comment: What does the nginx log say? add an error_log with 'debug' verbosity

Comment: Maybe nginx's trying to log ops onto unaccessible file/path, check file permissions and user:group nginx is starting by. If you don't see anything at logfiles, that might be the case.

Comment: Well...I got it to work. I think I failed to enable my vhost. I thought I symlinked correctly from sites available, but when I looked, it was not there. Once I fixed the symlink, it started logging to the default nginx logs in `/var/log/nginx/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- run `nginx -t` on the config file
- Check log files - both the ones you specified and possible "default" ones that nginx writes if it cannot use the specified ones, before loading config, or if it feels like it, and of course global logs that may contain error messages
- stop nginx, and start it manually (i.e. not using the init script) and look for output. Kill your nginx and start it using the init script afterwards.
- Check netstat if it shows nginx listening or not. If not, don't bother testing if it is reachable, find the cause. If it is listening, test it locally (wget) to find out if nginx or connectivity is broken.
- If it doesn't hurt (i.e. nothing else running on the machine), try rebooting it.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing really unusual about this configuration you've posted is the use of `deferred` in your `listen` directive.

It seems some web sites provide this in their sample configurations and "recommend" it but don't actually explain [what it does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8449058/1068283). (Which is not very much, unless it's set on both ends, and if it isn't, then things get really weird really fast, since this *technically* subtly breaks the TCP protocol.)

The absolute first thing I would do would be to remove this `deferred` option from your `listen` directive.

Even if this does not solve the problem, I would not put it back. If you want to investigate its supposed performance benefits later, you can do so in a carefully controlled test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall on your server blocking connection to 80 port? Try doing 'curl localhost' on server to check if it is locally reachable.

Comment: Good idea, but that's not it because enabling the default vhost works fine. It must be something with my specific vhost config.